# how to create a button that will automatically generate a filled template in pdffiller using data generated from google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, pdf, automation, integromat-apps

so i want to create a button that will trigger pdf Filler App to open a document filled with the data of the owner in the same row in google sheet. for example [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/am6MQ.png) in this image u can see that the buttons are for each owner so i want the button to be filled with the data and open the template with the latest update automatically. i found a solution that allow me to do it but not efficient bc i need to repeat the code for each button but this will result in long lines of codes and i want it to be created automatically using app script extension in google sheet.

i found a solution that allow me to do it but not efficient bc i need to repeat the code for each button but this will result in long lines of codes and i want it to be created automatically using app script extension in google sheet.
other solutions i found the use the increment method in the url to increase the row number but url for the template does not have any row number.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.